# Could we post a general disclaimer on the site, given the diversity of contributing members?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed an edit today that inserted in someone else's post, "This answer is from *_*_ perspective."
I understand the difficulties that arise in a community as divers as this one.  I also appreciate the sensitivity of those who are trying to ease the points of contention.

In view of the diversity of its members, could BH-SE just post a broad disclaimer somewhere on the site, something like,

> **Questions and Answers posted on this site do not necessarily reflect the beliefs of the site or its members.**

Contributors would naturally own their own perspective; and, since all contributors are expected to show their work, each would have to be responsible for their perspective and with it.